# appending all files in directory and adding a column in UNIX

Tags: unix, append

I have several output files in a directory; e.g.

```
out100

out200

out300

...

...
```

all these files contain a single column of several numerical energy values. I want to compile all these files into one long column within one file. I would also like to add an additional column so I know which original file it came from.... how would i go about doing this??

e.g.

```
100 6546

100 3566

100 3563

200 3566

200 ...

200 ... 

300 ... 

300 ... 

300 ...
.
.
.
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the example given by you, this will work.

```
awk '{print FILENAME, $0}' `ls out???` | sed 's/out//'
```